# How do I stop logs before Django sets up logging

Tags: django, logging

I have a call to Initialization() in wsgi.py in my django app that gets made before django calls setup().

Within that call to Initialization(), there is another call made to IdentityService() which is an imported library.

This results in the logs from IdentityService() going to STDOUT when my django app initializes and I want to suppress these logs.

The django app uses the normal LOGGING setting, configured by dictConfig().

Am I right in assuming that because the call on the Initialisation class gets made before configure_logging is called by setup(), the LOGGING dictionary can't control the logs of IdentityService() going to STDOUT?

Any suggestions for how I can stop these logs being sent to STDOUT?

Here's a trimmed version of the code to demonstrate:

```
# initialize_settings.py

import identity_connector


class Initialization:

    def setup_identity_service(self):
        django.conf.settings.IDENTITY_SERVICE = identity_connector.IdentityService()
        django.conf.settings.IDENTITY_SERVICE.login()  # calling this method of the IdentityService object sends messages to stdout - These are the logs I want to suppress

    def __call__(self):
        self.setup_identity_service()



# wsgi.py

import initialize_settings
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


initialize_settings.Initialization().__call__()

application = get_wsgi_application()



# settings.py

import logging_config

LOGGING = logging_config.logging_configuration  # this is the logging configuration dictionary that has my logging config in it (loggers, handlers, filters etc.). Once Django is 'setup', this is working as expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this - so sharing it here.

I had to disable the default logging configuration and manually configure logging by calling a new method in Initialization.

This stopped logs containing passwords from setup_identity_service going to stdout before Django calls setup().

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/logging/#disabling-logging-configuration

```
# initialize_settings.py

import identity_connector
import logging_config


class Initialization:

    def setup_logging(self):
        django.conf.settings.LOGGING_CONFIG = None
        logging.config.dictConfig(
            logging_config.logging_configuration  # this will be the dictionary containing your loggers, handlers, filters etc.
        )
        
    def setup_identity_service(self):
        django.conf.settings.IDENTITY_SERVICE = identity_connector.IdentityService()
        django.conf.settings.IDENTITY_SERVICE.login()

    def __call__(self):
        self.setup_logging()
        self.setup_identity_service()


# settings.py

LOGGING_CONFIG = None
```